# How do I make my add-on appear as a "primary" sidebar that appears on the far right?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-workspace, google-workspace-add-ons

We have an add-on that appears as a sidebar using the `Ui.showSidebar` function. To make this appear we are utilizing the `homepageTrigger` feature in `appsscript.json`

This works fine, however I notice that when you click the add-on icon the first thing that happens is a sidebar is opened, but a different sidebar compared to what eventually shows. This "primary" sidebar appears to appear then disappear very quickly and just triggers the second sidebar to appear.

How can I make my add-on just show in the first sidebar? It looks dodgy to have the sidebar appear and disappear quickly.

"Primary" sidebar (ignore the error):

[image]

Secondary sidebar:

[image]

appsscript.json

```
{
  "timeZone": "Australia/Sydney",
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "Drive",
        "serviceId": "drive",
        "version": "v2"
      }
    ]
  },
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.scriptapp",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/documents.currentonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/presentations",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.apps.readonly",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.locale",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
  ],
  "urlFetchWhitelist": [
    "https://cm234-wgs-1.icognition.cloud/",
    "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export",
    "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/export",
    "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/presentations/Export"
  ],
  "addOns": {
    "common": {
      "name": "Content Manager",
      "logoUrl": "https://cm234-wgs-1.icognition.cloud/CMServiceApiGoogle/TrimIcon/W64h64/trim.png",
      "homepageTrigger": {
        "runFunction": "showSidebar",
        "enabled": true
      }
    },
    "sheets": {},
    "docs": {},
    "slides": {}
  }
}
```

Code.gs

```
function showSidebar() {
  var sidebarName = "sidebar";

  if (getRecordUri() !== 0) {
    sidebarName = "existing_record_sidebar";
  }

  var ui =
    HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(sidebarName).setTitle(
      "Content Manager",
    );
  getUi().showSidebar(ui);
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so that we can see the code that you are using to create the problem.  Please post it into you question.

Comment: The UI sidebar and the addon sidebar do not occur in the same div.

Comment: I would also like to suggest if you are posting question, about a Google Workspace Add on, specifically about Card Lifecycle I really suggest providing the manifest so that the community will have better chance of understanding what is happening in your use case. Please do add a manifest on your question.

Comment: Why do we ignore the error?

Comment: @Cooper I have added the manifest

Comment: @TheMaster I purposefully triggered the error so the "primary" sidebar would remain on the screen long enough for me to take a screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you're using *Workspace addons*, but using `HtmlService` to provide a user interface. The primary sidebar is the one that should be created using `CardService`.  The secondary one is on top of primary one - created with `HtmlService`, which is primarily used in *Editor addons*. If you want to use the primary one, use [CardService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service) instead of `HtmlService` to create a user interface.

Comment: Thanks, could you point me to some documentation on how I'd use CardService instead of HtmlService to create a user interface?

Comment: Looking into this further it seems the CardService has very restricted UI capabilities, so I would basically have to rewrite the add-on from scratch for it to work - thanks for the pointers though.